# limit for one query in union of two sql queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am facing an issue while trying to merge the resultset of two sql queries for the same table.There is a call status column for the calls table.I want to have a resultset where I want to get 20 calls with status Completed and all calls with planned status for a contact from the same table called as Calls.Then order by the entire resultset by date and start time of call.I am trying to do something like this :

```
(SELECT * ' +
           'FROM calls ' +
           'WHERE primary_contact=' + id + ' ' +
           'AND callstatus="Planned")' ;
           'UNION (SELECT * ' +
           'FROM calls ' +
           'WHERE primary_contact=' + id + ' ' +
           'AND callstatus="Completed"' +
           'LIMIT 0,20)' +
           'ORDER BY calldate || " " ||  stime DESC ';
```

This query is not working for me.Can anyone please help me and let me know where Iam I going wrong?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get error message, or do you get wrong results? If you get wrong results, then how are they wrong? What you get and what you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM calls
 WHERE primary_contact = :id AND 
       callstatus = 'Planned'
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM (
           SELECT *
             FROM calls
            WHERE primary_contact = :id AND 
                  callstatus = 'Completed'
            LIMIT 20
       )
 ORDER BY calldate, stime;
```

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * ' +
           'FROM calls ' +
           'WHERE primary_contact=' + id + ' ' +
           'AND callstatus="Planned" UNION ' +
           'SELECT * ' +
           'FROM calls ' +
           'WHERE primary_contact=' + id + ' ' +
           'AND callstatus="Completed" ' +
           'LIMIT 0,10) ' +
           'ORDER BY calldate || " " ||  stime DESC '

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I had to make it inner query like I have posted above.But now the issue I am facing is that the LIMIT is getting set to entire resultset instead of getting applied only for Completed Calls.I tried to surround it with parenthesis but that is giving syntax issues.

Comment: Why did you have to change it? Was my query giving you wrong results? You're facing problem with `LIMIT`, because the `LIMIT` applies to all `SELECT`s, even those joined with `UNION`. Look at my query - I apply `LIMIT` only to the second subquery - it doesn't impact the outer `SELECT`. This is the whole point of enclosing one `SELECT` as an inner `SELECT` to have `LIMIT` restricted only to that inner `SELECT`.